# jQuery notification with ajaxget in one href

Tags: jquery, css, notifications

I have ajax XMLhttprequest link:

```
<a href='javascript:addtobasket100("|1|100|")' class="f">Add to basket</a>
```

Ajax below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addtobasket100(int) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("addtobasket100").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","add.php?a=" + int, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

I want call ajax http request to add.php and jquery notification in one click (when user add item to basket), does any have idea how do that?

I want use this jQuery notification:
http://marcojetson.github.io/jquery-notification/ and this example

```
$.createNotification({
    content: '<img src="https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/profile_images/770845756/45_normal.jpg"> Hi, I\'m GG Allin'
})
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code correctly. It makes it much quicker and easier for people to read, and means you're more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Yes I will next time, I was just paste from my working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats easy:

When you return from your ajax call just insert the code that creates the notification

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("addtobasket100").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            $.createNotification({
                content: 'Item Added Succesfully!!!'
            })
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you make just one more helping,

I also have div:
<div id="basket">129,00 USD</div> how I can call another url moneyinbasket.php and put content from php result to basket div.

Comment: But not in <div id="addtobasket100"></div> now I using this div for add to basket button (quantity and more..)

Comment: You can write data into many places by returning a valid javascript command and the using eval() to evaluate it. Or you can return hidden inputs with the data from the ajax, and then after returning from the ajax call, you set the values on your html from the hidden fields returned